# How to use custom output formats to create a printer-friendly template in hugo

Tags: templates, hugo, printing-web-page

I would like to be able to define an HTML template that is optimized for printing.  It would seem that Hugo custom output formats is exactly what I need but I am struggling to understand how to make it work.

Here is an excerpt from the `config.yaml` file that defines the new format:

```yaml
outputFormats:
  printFormat:
    name: print
    mediaType: text/html
    isHTML: true
    path: print

outputs:
  page:
    - HTML
    - print
  home:
    - HTML
    - RSS
  section:
    - HTML
    - RSS
  taxonomy:
    - HTML
    - RSS
  term:
    - HTML
    - RSS
```

I've also created `<theme>/layouts/_default/baseof.print.html` and `<theme>/layouts/_default/single.print.html`.

I don't get any errors when I try to build, however I also don't see any of the print templates generated.

I also don't fully understand what the url structure would look like to target the resource.  Here is what I've tried

```
https://<domain-name>/posts/<post-name>.print
https://<domain-name>/posts/<post-name>.print.html
https://<domain-name>/posts/print/<post-name>
https://<domain-name>/posts/<post-name>/print/index.html
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong in the configuration and what the URL would look like to access the custom out put?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to work out the issue. Here is the change to the `config.yaml` that made it work ...

```yaml
outputFormats:
  printFormat:
    name: print
    mediaType: text/html
    baseName: print
    isPlainText: false
    rel: alternate
    isHTML: false
    noUgly: true
    permalinkable: false
```

Having made this change the following url will now give me access to the "printer-friendly" template:

```
https://<domain-name>/posts/<post-name>/print.html
```